# Define generic return type on Interface

Tags: typescript

When building an React native app in TypeScript, I'm trying to build an abstraction layer between our API and Authentication packages. I'm thinking that it's possible to define an API-request with the corresponding return type as a simple object. Then that object can be passed to the Authentication layer that's in charge of enriching the request with an access token. Something like this:

```
// The generic request interface
interface Request<T> {
    url: string
    options: RequestOptions
    returnType: typeof T  // ERROR: 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)
}

// A declaration of an API request with return type
interface User {
    id: string
    name: string
    age: string
}

const getUser = (id: string): Request<User> => ({
    url: `www.example.com/users/${id}`,
    options: {
        method: 'GET'
    },
    returnType: typeof User  // ERROR: 'User' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)
})

// A generic function that enriches API requests with an access token
const authRequest = async <T>(request: Request<T>): Promise<T> => {
    // Fetches the access token
    const accessToken = await getAccessToken()
    // `fireRequest` is in charge of firing the API request with provided data from `request` and `accessToken`.
    // It's a generic function that returns a Promise<request.returnType>
    return fireRequest(request, accessToken)    
}

// This is how an API request would be triggered from the call site
const doStuff = async () => {
    const user = await authRequest(getUser('some-user-id'))
}
```

What's the correct way to tie a specify `returnType` to the `Request` interface? How can I get rid of the errors caused by `returnType`?

If I simply remove `returnType` from the `Request` interface, but keep the generic definition, I can make it work, but Typescript is giving me a warning that `'T' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)`:

```
interface Request<T> { // 'T' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
    url: string
    options: RequestOptions
}
```

Comment: `T` refers to a type already, so `typeof T` doesn't make sense. Simply write `returnType: T`

Comment: This won't work for me. Then I'd have to supply a value of `T` when creating the Request object. The value is not present until after the API request has returned. It's not possible to pass a value of a `User` when describing the endpoint (in `getUser`)

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding you right, but would `returnType: T | null` work? You can assign `null` as a default until your data has loaded.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't have any runtime type information or reflection; types are completely erased when transpiled to runtime.  If you want some kind of string-to-type mapping, you need to build it yourself.  For example, [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NlL2eN) shows a "Type Registry" that you add a key to, so the compiler understands which `returnTypes` are valid, and what they map to. Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing? (Please mention @jcalz in your reply to notify me)

Answer (score 0):

T is already a type, so you don't need to use typeof T, you can use it directly:

```
interface Request<T> {
url: string
options: RequestOptions
returnType: T
}
```

Comment: This does not work. Then I'd have to supply a value of T when creating the request object. The value is not present until after the API request has returned.

Comment: If you are using generics then you must replace T with a type when implementing the interface. Just look at the API return format and create a type for it. In your getUser function for example, just change return type for User instead of typeof User.